# mex error: Cannot export mexFunction: symbol not defined

Tags: c++, matlab, mingw, mex

When I run the `setup` function of [MatConvNet](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/practicals/cnn/), I get the following error(s):

```
>> setup
Warning: VL_NNCONV() does not seem to be compiled. Trying to compile it now. 
> In setup (line 14) 
Building with 'MinGW64 Compiler (C++)'.
Error using mex
Cannot export mexFunction: symbol not defined
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status


Error in vl_compilenn>mex_compile (line 312)
  mex(mopts{:}) ;

Error in vl_compilenn (line 270)
obj_files = mex_compile(opts, cpp_src, bld_dir, mex_opts);

Error in setup (line 15)
  vl_compilenn('enableGpu', opts.useGpu, 'verbose', opts.verbose) ;
```

I didn't have a mex compiler so I installed MinGW with MATLAB R2015b's directives. It sees the compiler, but it cannot compile. I don't have any idea how to fix this..

Thanks for any help !

### Edit

I'm using MATLAB R2015b on a 64-bit Windows 7, and the add-on I installed is called `MATLAB Support for the MinGW-w64 C/C++ Compiler from TDM-GCC`

Comment: Can you compile c++, mex code using mex my_function.cpp (for some arbitrary cpp file)? Is this purely an issue with setting up the mex compiler? Or does it involve interactions with the MatConvNet setup script?

Comment: @MatthewGunn I remember making the setup function work before (probably with a different compiler though) so it is probably about mingw installation. Let me try your suggestion. I tried with an empty .cpp file, the same error: `Cannot export mexFunction: symbol not defined
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

Comment: How about something like: (1) get some real source to compile, eg. `copyfile(fullfile(matlabroot,'extern','examples','mex','yprime.c'),'.','f')` then (2) `mex yprime.c`
That should give 'MEX completed successfully.' Try some working mex source where mexFunction is properly defined in the source.

Comment: I think that error generally occurs when the compiled cpp source does not include a function "void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])"

Comment: Do all cpp files need to have that in order to get mex'ed? Anyway, I solved my problem simply by installing (and setting as default C++ compiler) Microsoft Windows SDK 7.1 (C++). But let me try your suggestion. Yes, it works with both compilers. So maybe if I add mexFunction to the source of MatConvNet, it could work. Anyway, I don't want to mess it up further :) But if that's the solution, please post it as an answer. Thanks for all the help !

Comment: I wouldn't mess with the source of MatConvNet either. The error code sounds like some kinda weird linking issue. I was just trying to narrow down whether the problem was with compiling everywhere or this particular package. Glad to hear using microsoft C++ compiler solves hte problem!

Comment: @jeff how did you set SDK 7.1 as default?

Comment: I am trying to mex multiple files like this mex computeSpikeListInhib.c quickSort.c nrutil.c and last 2 files don't have mexFunction in them. The guy who wrote the code got it compiled but i get error on windows!